# The return type 'Future<dynamic>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context. after adding const and also returning container doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart, builder

I'm trying to make an image text recognition app where I pass image to methods for getting the result as recognized text, but I get the Future builder error while passing the image through the navigator push routing for a methos passing.

My Code is :

[image]

> This is giving the error

[image]

[image]

Comment: after adding the `builder: (context) => const scanText(image!),` sayes this `The name 'scanText' isn't a class` where I added as a future methos right after that already.

Comment: add text based code instead of screenshots

Comment: what you want to achieve can you explain ?

Comment: I want to pass the method through a navigator push, like this `Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const scanText(image!),
                        ),
                      );`

Comment: do you want to show the dialog when the button is pressed ?

Comment: I want that if that button is pressed then it will go to the mentioned method and will take the info from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251572/discussion-between-mou-biswas-and-munsif-ali).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `Navigator.push()` & `Navigator.pop()` we use these to go to other files like classes from one class or file .
here we're passing parameters as image file within methods within one class.
So, in this case `Navigator.push()` isn't working out. Just the name of method with parameter would work like these `scanText(image!);`